# Technical Issue: Overcoming Electronic Stamp (E-Materai) Issues in PDF Document with MPDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I have a document with an electronic stamp (E-Materai), set as SetSourceFile in the latest PHP MPDF library (version 8.2). After execution, the electronic stamp is not recognized (it doesn't appear as it does in the original document). The document itself is rendered perfectly.

Seeking guidance on how to address this issue and ensure proper rendering of the electronic stamp with MPDF 8.2.

Has anyone else encountered this issue, or do you have any other ideas to resolve this problem?

Here is the simple code that I implemented:

```
$mpdf       = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$file_name  = 'Document.pdf';
$pagecount  = $mpdf->SetSourceFile($file_name);

for ($i=1; $i<=$pagecount; $i++) {
    
    $import_page = $mpdf->ImportPage($i);

    $size = $mpdf->getTemplateSize($import_page);

    $mpdf->UseTemplate($import_page, 0, 0, $size['width'], $size['height'], true);

    if ($i < $pagecount){
        $mpdf->AddPage($size['orientation']);
    }
}

$mpdf->Output('Draft Template Item _'. date('Ymd_His') .'.pdf', 'I');
```

Output Original File vs After Render with MPDF.
[Click Here to View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do7T3.png)

Previously, I was using MPDF version 8.0, and I assumed that after updating to the latest version, I could resolve this issue. However, it turns out that's not the case.

I hope the rendering results with MPDF will match the original file.

Comment: The point of E-Meterai is that its presence validates the integrity of the PDF. It **should** disappear when you modify it. So it's working as intended.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, Certainly! The primary purpose of E-Materai is to validate the integrity of documents once they are signed. I am working on incorporating a digital signature into documents that have already been stamped with E-Materai through my PHP application (leveraging the MPDF Library).

Is there a way to ensure the validity of E-Materai when adding a Digital Signature through MPDF?

Comment: You will have to put in the E-Meterai **and** add the digital signature at the same time, and only then save the PDF. Doing one after the other, and save as PDF in between, will always invalidate the first one you apply.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you for your invaluable advice. Taking this step may prove to be challenging as I rely on services from an external party for the implementation of official electronic stamps in accordance with government regulations in my country.